# Davening behind a mechitzah - Poreish Min HaTzibbur?

Tags: tefilla, mechitza-partition, tefillah-betzibbur

I have noticed a trend in many orthodox synagogues where men will daven in the women's section despite there being plenty of room in the men's section to sit and pray.

Since the function of the mechitzah is to be chotzetz - to create a physical division between the men and women during tefillah, one who is davening behind the mechitzah is, for all intents and purposes, in a separate domain.

Barring issues such as a lack of space and agoraphobia which would otherwise compel a person to pray there, would intentionally davening behind a mechitzah (and thereby actively separating yourself from the rest of the congregation) fall under the principle of being poreish min hatzibbur?

Comment: "for all intents and purposes" That's not clear at all.

Comment: Poresh min hatzibbur? He is in the room. I would ask rather how is he mitztaref to the tzibbur for tefillah betzibbur

Comment: Besides any other issues, I would strongly recommend avoiding this practice, since it makes the women's section look very unwelcoming to any women who happen to come to daven.

Comment: @DoubleAA Feel free to bring sources that question the premise of that statement. ***IF*** the mechitzah is designed to create a separate domain, then being behind the mechitzah, by definition, means you are in a separate domain.

Comment: @Nafkamina Someone can be physically "present" and still be considered a poresh - See Taanis where one who doesn't fast with the tzibbur is considered a poresh min hatzibbur even if he is "present" in other ways.

Comment: This person is abstaining from nothing rather he doing the same thing as everyone else just in a different place

Comment: @Nafkamina Al achas kama vikama! The person who doesn't fast is engaged in a shev (one that isn't externally visible at that), here he is actively moving apart from the tzibbur!

Comment: Not shver. Fasting is not shev in a taanis tzibbur.

Comment: The rasha as mentioned in the pesach seder is considered poresh min hatzibbur, even though he is physically present and engaged in the seder!

Comment: Thats not a rayah. Its not meant literally

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky See section G http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimer2-1.htm

Comment: @IsaacMoses You write: "it makes the women's section look very unwelcoming to any women who happen to come to daven".  Our Rav has asked us not to daven in the women's section for that reason.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the link. Fascinating (but long) read. Keep in mind that the article was approaching this from the opposite side - we consider the other side of the mechitza a separate domain ***by default,*** but there are ways to incorporate conjoined spaces we would normally consider separate. By placing himself in a bidi'eved conjoined domain rather than ***with*** the tzibbur, a man might very well be considered different than a woman in this circumstance.

Comment: Rav Yaakov held its fine(not sure lchatchila) ,see bmichitzos Rabbeini

Comment: @sam can you add a link? I would love to see his reasoning.

Comment: I have the sefer ,I don't believe it's available online